# Yes, questions can be Too Localized. But usually they are at far greater risk of being Too Broad

Tags: discussion, policy, closing-questions

Seriously, from the word go, we need to be pre-emptive about requiring people to ask *specific enough questions that we can offer concise and definitive answers*. For example, ["How does one go about developing a language for a particular culture in your world?"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/19/17) is basically asking "how do I con-lang?" – which is the subject of myriad websites, blogs, and *entire books*. A big chunk of the field of linguistics comes into play in answering that question, and Stack Exchange already has a whole site dedicated to that.

It's a fascinating question. I love reading any solid thoughts on the subject. But it's not something that you can answer concisely and definitively, and that is what the Stack Exchange format is good at.

Instead, `constructed-languages` could be an entire tag, with potentially hundreds of questions. Every individual culture on every individual world could *easily* be a separate question – and a difficult one, at that! I don't know if such questions *are* on topic here – maybe they should go to Linguistics.SE instead – but I do know that no Stack Exchange is ever going to be able to give that question the response it deserves.

So please: let's work together, as a community, to focus questions. Focused questions are real, detailed, describe distinct parameters for answering and judging the worth of answers. A question that amounts to the entirety of a culture's history and a detailed breakdown of their environment is too much – that'd be Too Localized, as well as kind of a ridiculous thing to expect us to answer – but brief, general descriptions of the *actual problem you are trying to solve* are the way to get good answers out of a Stack Exchange site.

The other really good solution, for those who honestly are looking for answers to the big questions, is ask for resources. "How do I con-lang?" is too broad. "Where can I learn about making a constructed languages for a (fantasy/futuristic/alien/whatever) world?" is answerable and hopefully something this community would know something about (but make sure it's not a Shopping Question).

Answer (score 10):

This is a very good point. Most of the questions I've seen so far are just that. Questions instead of problems. Including those problems could help narrow many of those "too broad" questions down to "just right" size. It might be worth making that point on any question that isn't - for lack of a better term - bite size. After all, we want to make sure the quality of questions in the beta represent what we want to see on the site later.